# Reading Rails database values from a URL

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my ruby on rails project, I have a share model which stores share basic values like share name, market cap, current value, book value etc. In rails, when I want to create a new share record, instead of user entering the details, I want them to enter a URL from a financial website and I want my code to read the share basic parameters from the financial website. URL is not stored in the database.

for example: If the user enters http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/food-processing/nestleindia/NI. My code should read below parameters and store it in database.
 name: Nestle , price: 5628, market cap: 54,366.89, book value: 352.69 etc

I read webpages using Nokogiri. And since reading from web takes time, I have to use delayed_job as well.
  My new.html.erb has only one input which is URL which sends a post request to "create" action. Now URL is not part of my model.  I have declared a :url parameter inside the model as below:

```
 class Share < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessor :url
 end
```

Now I am bit confused as to how to handle this url in my model/controller. Which is the best place to implement URL reading method? is it controller or model? 
   If I pass the url to model, how to implement the method to get url and read the parameters?
  If I read the parameters in controller, how do I pass them to model?

I am not able to access the url parameter inside my controller as well. When I call my method to readthe webpage, I get an error saying, empty url is passed:

My new.html.erb:

```
 <%= form_for(@share)    do |f| %>
 <p>
      <%= f.label :url %>
      <%= f.text_field :url, autofocus: true %>
 </p>
 <p>
 <%= f.submit 'Pull the data'%>
 </p>
 <% end %>
```

and my current create method in my controller:

```
 def create
   @url = params[:url]
   #readShareBasic(url) is a method to read the website and return a hash
   @share = Share.new(readShareBasic(url)).permit(:name, :current_price, :year_low, :year_high, :current_PE_ratio, :market_cap, :book_value, :description, :price_to_book_value))
redirect_to shares_url
```

end

Here in controller, I am not able to access the content of params[:url] either.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the controller create method to get the url and create/save a new share instance. You don't need the accessor in the model. If you look in the source code of your form, you'll see how the form data is being passed.

In the controller, its better to separate the strong params into its own method.

```
def
  @url = params[:share][:url]
  @share = Share.new(share_params)
  @share_details = readShareBasic(@url)
  # assign values from readShareBasic to the share instance as needed
  # save share
end

private
def share_params
  params.require(:share).permit(:name, :current_price, :year_low, :year_high, :current_PE_ratio, :market_cap, :book_value, :description, :price_to_book_value, :url)
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @margo. If I want to include delayed_job here, should I define the whole share record creation in a new method and call it using delay? something like :    \@url = params[:share][:url]    self.delay.readAndCreateShare(\@url)